# Is there a workaround for Optional ParseDate SuperCsvCellProcessorException in SuperCSV?

Tags: java, supercsv

I'm using SuperCSV in java to read a csv file.  I have a column containing dates but the records may not be populated so I set it to optional.  In my CellProcessor I define the field as

```
    ...,
    new Optional(new ParseDate("MM/dd/yyyy",true)),
    ...
```

When ParseDate encounters an empty cell it returns "...SuperCsvCellProcessorException:'      ' could not be parsed as a Date."

How do I continue processing the parseDate in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only empty columns (i.e. empty String) are mapped to null when Super CSV reads the CSV - a space will be read as a space. This is because whitespace is meant to be important in [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), the CSV mimetype specification.

So `Optional` won't bypass the next processor for a space. You can use this processor setup instead:

```
new Optional(new Token(" ", null, new ParseDate("MM/dd/yyyy",true)));
```

This will return `null` if it encounters null (i.e. empty String in the CSV) or a single space, and bypass trying to parse it as a date.

You could also enable the [surroundingSpacesNeedQuotes](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html#Ignoring_surrounding_spaces_if_theyre_not_within_quotes) preference to get around this, but just be aware that this will also strip out any leading/trailing spaces - which you might not want.